# Pointing Selenium toward certain input, can't figure out xpath, css selector, etc

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

I'm working with a webpage that, among other things, has a few input forms which are different only in their `input id`'s.  They're formed like this:

```
<input class="form-control" id="post_email" name="post_email" style="line-height: 1.42857; width: 650px;" type="text">
```

How, using Selenium, could I possibly select this?  I've tried:

```
em = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//post_email')
em = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#post_email')
em = browser.find_element_by_class_name('post_email')
```

Each raises the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//post_email"}
```

Except with the relevant methods and selectors changed, of course.  I'm having a really tough time figuring this out.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for xpath:

```
//input[@id = "post_email"]
```

or

```
//*[@id = "post_email"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way - "by id" locator:

```
em = browser.find_element_by_id("post_email")
```